# Simple SQL Joining Operation

Tags: php, mysql, join

My database structure is like this:

```
   Members table

   |id|username|...

   Messages table
   |id|fromId|toId|content
```

In the messages table id refers to the message ID, in the members it refers to the user id (which is the same Id that is in fromId and toId).  I want to do a join query FROM messages WHERE id=SOME_MESSAGE_ID that pulls the following result set

```
   |id(message id)|fromId|fromUsername(username that corresponds to fromId)|toId|toUsername(username that corresponds to toId)|content
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the members table twice but using different aliases:

```
SELECT
    messages.id,
    messages.fromId,
    from_member.username AS fromUsername,
    messages.toId,
    to_member.username AS toUsername,
    messages.content
FROM messages 
JOIN members AS from_member ON from_member.id = message.fromId
JOIN members AS to_member ON to_member.id = message.toId
```

Comment: Ahh i didn't know you can JOIN twice.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Have an upvote :)

Comment: Just a quick note, using `JOIN` will cause the query to act like an `INNER JOIN` and won't return messages where one of the Member records is missing.

Comment: One more thing, the table names as all lowercase which could be a problem depending on the operating system on which your database server software is installed. Some are case-sensitive.

Comment: That's ok, a member record will never go missing.  Is yours or the left join one more efficent?  Also I edited the names as appropriate.  It works well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT    `Message`.`id`,
          `Message`.`fromId`,
          `From`.`username` AS `fromUsername`,
          `Message`.`toId`,
          `To`.`username` AS `toUsername`
          `Message`.`content`
FROM      `Messages` AS `Message`
LEFT JOIN `Members` AS `From`
ON        `From`.`id` = `Message`.`fromId`
LEFT JOIN `Members` AS `To`
ON        `To`.`id` = `Message`.`toId`
WHERE     `Message`.`id` = 1
```

For more information on SELECT queries, [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Is your LEFT JOIN one more efficent than the dual JOIN above, or the same?

Comment: @user974896 - It's not more efficient. The only real difference is that the `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` columns instead of not returning a row at all. So, for example, if you remove a user, the `LEFT JOIN` would still allow you to see the message but the `username` would be `NULL`.